# sql - perform join excluding repeated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem, I use sql server, I need to join two tables by a field, but when performing the join I am duplicating the key field, my query is as follows:

```
select A.*, B.*
from Database.dbo.Module1 A
LEFT JOIN RRHH.dbo.Module2 B on A.key1 = B.key1
```

is it possible to exclude from the select the key1 field from the module2 table?

In the tables, I have another few duplicate fields, I could write every field I need from the tables in the select, but , it would be easier to exclude the fields I don't need. Consider that each table has hundreds of fields that are needed.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: usually you need only a dew columns, so that the list is short. And SELECT * is a bad habit, as it, tells you nothing about the purpose of that query

Comment: Take a look at Redgate's *SQLPrompt* tool which integrates with SSMS and offers useful features that can help with large # columns.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. Specify fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "`all columns except <these>`" syntax in T-SQL, sorry.

Of course it's very easy to generate the list of columns from any table by simply dragging the `Columns` node onto a query window. This works in both SSMS and Azure Data Studio, as I describe [in this Bad Habits post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list):

[image]

[image]

Then just prefix the ones you need, and delete the ones you don't.

Comment: I had no idea that it is possible to get the fields/columns of a table in that way. Thanks you.